# MacBook Pro mid 2012 lagging

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, lag, macos-catalina

I bought a used MacBook Pro 2012. It has a new SSD disk, and I have replaced memory and battery - and I have also reset disk partitions and installed Catalina from a USB stick.

Still the MacOS often freezes. Simple operations lead to the colored wheel mouse pointer. It happens also for operations with no network traffic.

Even when I disabled Spotlight indexing (by adding all of the drive to th exception list), the lagging still happens.

I have also reset PRAM and SMC. And the same problem was with Mojave installed instead of Catalina.

I have also run a hardware analysis (by software), and 
it reported no problems.

My question is this, what else can I try? What can be the cause of the lagging?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The solution was disabling the setting **Put hard disks to sleep when possible** in **Energy Saver settings**.

My Mac had an HDD originally, but now it has an SSD. Don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT202824